# SLComposerViewController crashing while testing in Device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, social-networking

Im developing an app where i need suport of social framework. So I decide to go with this

```
SLComposeViewController *cntrlr = [[SLComposeViewController alloc]init];
cntrlr =  [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

But its weird that this code was running fine even 15 - 20 days back , but now the app is crashing due to this line of code while im testing it on ipod but when i'm testing it on simulator its working fine. 
  Please Help me friends...

Answer (score 1):

please check your deployment target is 6.0 or not because  `SLComposeViewController` available in iOS 6.0 or letter

[image]

please check this referace link:-

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205

Comment: Thank you Nitin... yup I got u... :-)